# Update the value of a dictionary with elements in the lists Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I've created a list and a dictionary for calculating amino acid frequencies.

I want to basically replace the values in the dictionary with values in the list.

So for example,

what I have now is.

`L1 = [0.0429, 0.0071, 0.05, 0.0929, 0.0429, 0.0143, 0.0071, 0.0429, 0.0929, 0.1143, 0.0643, 0.0643, 0.05, 0.0286, 0.0286, 0.0643, 0.0857, 0.0714, 0.0143, 0.0214]`

and

`D1 = OrderedDict([('A', 6), ('C', 1), ('D', 7), ('E', 13), ('F', 6), ('G', 2), ('H', 1), ('I', 6), ('K', 13), ('L', 16), ('M', 9), ('N', 9), ('P', 7), ('Q', 4), ('R', 4), ('S', 9), ('T', 12), ('V', 10), ('W', 2), ('Y', 3)])`

I want to replace every value in `D1` to values in `L1`.
So for example I want `([('A', 0.0429),('C',0.0071)....` and so on.

This is the code that creates the list (`L1`) and the dictionary(`D1`).

```
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(f1,'fasta'):

        sorted_dict = (collections.OrderedDict(sorted(Counter(seq_record.seq).items())))
        total = float(sum(Counter(seq_record.seq).values()))
        print sorted_dict
        aa_frequency =(round(value/total,4) for key, value in sorted_dict.items())
        aa_frequency_value = []
        for i in aa_frequency:
            aa_frequency_value.append(i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty straightforward since you already have the values and keys in order.

```
for val, key in zip(L1, D1):
    D1[key] = val
```

Seems like you should probably just do this in-place, since you're not adding or deleting elements

```
total = float(um(Counter(seq_record.seq).values()))
for key,val in sorted_dict.items():
    newval = round(val/total, 4)
    sorted_dict[key] = newval
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted,